# How to print data in an array of objects with mongodb and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am trying to append some data to a div with ng-repeat.

[image]

I am using angularjs and MongoDB without mongoose. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An array of objects from server:

```
[
    {
        _id: "5a733e96aa3c4e1202b347e5",
        image: "lerem",
        title: "Hydration",
        about: "Hydration is key",
        article: "hydor lorem ipsum",
        __v: 0
    },
    {
        _id: "5a7345b1aa3c4e1202b347e6",
        image: "lerem",
        title: "Hydration",
        about: "Hydration is key",
        article: "hydor loremm",
        __v: 0
    },
    {
        _id: "5a735c752aaeb91470fcda61",
        image: "lerem",
        title: "Hydration",
        about: "Hydration is key",
        article: "hydor lorm",
        __v: 0
    }
]
```

**Angularjs ng-repeat:**

```
<div ng-controller="ArticleController" ng-repeat="articles in articles | filter:article" class="articles">
    <h1>{{article.image}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.about}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.article}}</h1>
</div>
```

**controller for article:**

```
$http.get("/articles", function(articles) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="ArticleController" ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:article" class="articles">
    <h1>{{article.image}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.about}}</h1>
    <h1>{{article.article}}</h1>
</div>
```

should work. Please note that I changed `articles in articles` to `article in articles` for distinguishing purpose. Also, it is advisable to use Mongoose while working with angular. Kind of makes things easier to work with.

Comment: It still is only showing the data when I highlight the localhost:8080/articles and then press return. It is like the view is not active.

Comment: try removing `|filter:article` and then check if you are able to get anything.

Comment: Still the same. If I refresh the array of objects loads to the screen but not in the view just on a blank white screen

Comment: can you provide screenshot?

Comment: i have edited my answer a bit. Try now. You were providing articles to loop in articles which is causing this issue. just change the looping variable name to article and it should work.

Comment: Nope still nothing. Copied and pasted your answer in. I have the same site build in Angular CLI with mongoose I was trying to not use mongoose.